# Razor component System.nullreferenceexception at GetFromJsonAsync

Tags: json, blazor

Student studying FullSD encountered an error whilst following lab that my teacher can't figure out.

Have a page where I can create an entry that can be displayed. But when I refresh to view the newly added entry, I get a loading error. When looking at it from Developer Tools, it calls System.nullreferenceexception. Despite this, the entry can still be viewed from datatable in Visual Studios

The error references a block of code starting at line 37 of my Index.razor for this page, which my lecturer narrowed down to being this:

```
 protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Bookings = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Booking>>($"{Endpoints.BookingsEndpoint}");
    }
```

Entire Index.razor:

```
@page "/bookings/"
@inject HttpClient _client
@inject IJSRuntime js
@attribute [Authorize]

<h3 class="card-title">Car Bookings</h3>
<br />

<a href="/bookings/create" class="btn btn-secondary">
    <span class="oi oi-plus"></span>
    Create New Booking
</a>
<br />
<br />

@if (Bookings == null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Loading Bookings...</div>
}

else
{
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Booking Id</th>
                <th>Customer License</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Duration in days</th>
                <th>Plate Number</th>
                <th>Actions</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var booking in Bookings)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@booking.Id</td>
                    <td>@booking.CustomerId</td>
                    <td>@booking.DateCreated.Date.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")</td>
                    <td>@(booking.DateIn != nullDT ? (booking.DateIn - booking.DateOut).TotalDays.ToString() : "To Be Determined")</td>
                    <td>@booking.Vehicle.LicensePlateNumber</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/bookings/view/@booking.Id" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="oi oi-book"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/bookings/edit/@booking.Id" class="btn btn-warning">
                            <span class="oi oi-pencil"></span>
                        </a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(()=>Delete(booking.Id))">
                            <span class="oi oi-delete"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private List<Booking> Bookings;
    private DateTime nullDT = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Bookings = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Booking>>($"{Endpoints.BookingsEndpoint}");
    }

    async Task Delete(int bookingId)
    {
        var booking = Bookings.First(q => q.Id == bookingId);
        var confirm = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", $"Do you want to delete {booking.Id}?");

        if (confirm)
        {
            await _client.DeleteAsync($"{Endpoints.BookingsEndpoint}/{bookingId}");
            await OnInitializedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected the page to display the newly created entry as I have done with previously created pages in my Lab Workbook

Can anyone else provide some insight?

Edit: Here's my Booking class

```
using System;
namespace CarRentalManagement.Shared.Domain
{
    public class Booking:BaseDomainModel
    {
        public DateTime DateOut { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateIn { get; set; }
        public int VehicleId { get; set; }
        public virtual Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check the values of the properties, from which you are using properties/methods, are never null for every element in Bookings (ex: `Vehicle`).

Comment: Show the `Booking` class.

Comment: And where is defined the Endpoints variable?

Comment: @H H added an image of my class to main post

Comment: No, that is a picture of a database record. Add the C# code as text.

Comment: Changed it to the block of code. My lecturer recommended that I delete my migrations and database and then add-migration & update database but that did not work.